# accessing php soapservice from C#

Tags: c#, php, mysql, web-services, soap

well i wanted to make a simple webservice that searches the db and return the data i know i can do it with mysql connector but this is just to learn how to use soaps here is the code for php soap server

```
require_once ('lib/nusoap.php');

$namespace = "http://localhost/webservice/index.php?wsdl";
$server = new soap_server();
$server->configureWSDL("DBQuery");
$server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = $namespace;
$server->register(
    'QueryMsg',
    array('name'=>'xsd:string'),
    array('return'=>'xsd:string'),
    $namespace,
    false,
    'rpc',
    'encoded',
    'returns data from database');

function QueryMsg($query)
{
    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','webserivce');


    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        return "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    if(!isset($query) or strpos(strtolower($query),'select')<=-1)
    {
        return "invalid order";
    }
    else
    {

        mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$query);
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $data[] = $row;}

                return json_encode($data);

    }
}
// create HTTP listener
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
exit();
?>
```

it works when i try calling it from a php soap client but when i try adding this http:// localhost /webservice/index.php in visual studio as service refernce to consume it from C# application i get an error here it is

```
The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost/webservice/index.php'.
The content type text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 700 bytes of the response were: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode xsi:type="xsd:string">SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode><faultactor xsi:type="xsd:string"></faultactor><faultstring xsi:type="xsd:string">Operation &apos;&apos; is not defined in the WSDL for this service</faultstring><detail xsi:type="xsd:string"></detail></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>'.
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

solved : well it was easy actually there is two ways either use WCF and change encoding to ISO-8859-1
or change encoding of the web service itself by adding this line `$server->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';` after creating the soap server

Comment: do you get a valid WSDL when you visit http://localhost/webservice/index.php?wsdl ?

Comment: how do i know if it's valid all i get is this text This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below. 
and there is a whole lot of xml below it

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding the service WSDL with a tool like SOAP U.I. and see what kind of errors you get back from that.  It's a little more agnostic than adding a web reference with C#, and might disclose more details about why at the client level you can't consume this.

I'm happy to help you troubleshoot this with a little more information.  Are you running this service on the same machine where you're running the client from?  If it's complaining about being unable to correlate the file `http://localhost/webservice/index.php` to something I wonder if the discovery process is trying to evaluate a file that can't be found.  I.E. an import operation in your source WSDL that points to a URL the client can't resolve.